# Unable to connect web browser after installation apex 5.1

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle11gr2

I installed Oracle Apex 5.1 in Oracle Database 11.2.0.1.0 with Operating System Oracle Linux 6.7. All Steps completed successfully

```
SELECT comp_name, version, status FROM dba_registry WHERE comp_id='APEX';

Oracle Application Express       5.1.0.00.45            VALID

select username,created from all_users where USERNAME like '%APEX%';

APEX_LISTENER                  04-SEP-19
APEX_PUBLIC_USER               04-SEP-19
APEX_050100                    04-SEP-19
APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN_USER       04-SEP-19
APEX_REST_PUBLIC_USER          04-SEP-19

select dbms_xdb.gethttpport from dual;

GETHTTPPORT
-----------
   8181
```

When I try access on web browser then unable to connect

```
http://ipaddress:8181/apex/apex_admin
```

How to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: What does "unable to connect" mean? Any error? If so, which one?

Comment: @Littlefoot  Browser showing unable to connect page

Comment: Most browsers will give more information than that. At least a HTTP error in the 4xx or 5xx range. Might be hidden behind a link or in the console log.